# How to get Magento store currency

Tags: magento, locale, xml-rpc, currency

I'm using Magento XML-RPC api. 
I haven't found how to get the current store country or currency used for the products.
Is it possible to get the currency information through Magento XML-RPC api.

Any link to documentation is very helpful thank you.

Comment: Did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 20):

Store currency code eg. **USD**

> $currency_code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();

store currency symbol eg. **$**

> $currency_symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency( $currency_code
>   )->getSymbol();

store currency name eg. **US Dollar**

> $currency_name = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency( $currency_code
>   )->getName();

[Reference](http://www.techdilate.com/code/magento-current-store-currency-details-currency-code-currency-symbol-currency-name/)

Comment: this threw me for a loop Mage is no deprecated for magento2

Answer (score 9):

Here you go:

```
$storeID = <whatever your store id is>;

Mage::app()->getStore($storeID)->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 
Unfortunately I can't do it. Consider that I'm a third party application developer. I just have permissions to access Magento store through Magento XML-RPC api. And I'm using Java for XML-RPC requests.
What I'm trying to do is get current currency code through one of the API calls.

Comment: I am facing the same problem..please someone give an example to call a method like getting all the sales order list in java through xmlrpc